# Salvar arquivo txt no Matlab

Tags: matlab

Boas,

Eu tenho um programa que roda em loop e eu preciso salvar os resultados de cada *loop*.
Dentro do *loop* eu chamo diversas funções e em cada função eu preciso salvar os resultados.

eu tenho usado em cada função algo do tipo:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','a+');
fprintf(fid,'CoF Inícial:  %5.5f \n',mib);
fprintf(fid,'CoF Final:  %2.5f \n',min(miBPT));
fclose(fid);
```

ele tem salvado no arquivo `file.txt`, mas tem salvado em linha uma informação na frente da outra o que dificulta muito a leitura.

o comando `\n` funciona somente no ambiente do *matlab* não quando salva o arquivo.

Como eu poderia salvar em formato de coluna?

Answer (score 1):

Eu gosto de utilizar a função [dlmwrite](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html)

Essa função possui opções de atributos que podem te ajudar a definir como os dados são salvos no arquivo, você pode determinar delimitador, precisão numérica, pular linha, etc, um exemplo de uso seria:

```
dlmwrite(nomedoseuarquivo, seusdados, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', '%.6f','newline','pc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Este problema é um clássico dos problemas *windows* vs *unix*.

Além da resposta do [ederwander](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/300357/88991), uma opcão que eu normalmente use é a [funcão save](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), não sei se ela faz appendix, mas no manual ela deve te informar. Ela salva da maneira correta no seu sistema.

Porém, caso você queira usar o seu código, basta apenas modificar o seu código, seja através de como você [abre o arquivo](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) ou como você escreve.

Coloquei todas as opcões abaixo.

```
save('myfilename.dat','myvar','-ascii')


% the modifier 't' solves this issue
f=fopen('textfile.dat','at');
fprintf(f,'%4.2f \n',myvar);
fclose(f);


%the "enter" is a linefeed(\n) + carriagereturn(\r)
f=fopen('textfile.dat','a');
fprintf(f,'%4.2f \r\n',myvar);
fclose(f);
```

Nesta caso, `myvar` é uma variavel no formato coluna. A saída em todos os caso é no formato de coluna.